# Tool(s) for Converting Ms Access DB to Firebird Embedded

Tags: ms-access, firebird, jet, migrate

I have Ms Access 2002 database that I need to convert to Firebird 2.5 embedded. What tool(s) that I can use to achieve this? Preferably freeware ones.

Thanks!

Comment: AFF, if you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ESF Database Migration Toolkit](http://www.easyfrom.net/) . It is not free, but it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

[Interbase Datapump](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/datapump/index.asp) can make this !

Also [MDBtoFB](http://www.firebase.com.br/fb/downloads.php?busca=mdb) (even if you don't read portuguese)